# Route VPN users to another server while maintainance

Tags: openvpn

To keep the OpenVPN server updated, latest security patches should be applied constantly, which sometimes requires the server restart. But, the server may have multiple connected users at the moment, so can't restart instantly. However, there is another OpenVPN server running, so is it possible to route the connected users to the new server without showing any disconnections at the user end?